# Why does deploying a Kong ingress controller auto provisions a Azure load balancer in Azure Openshift kubernetes

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, azure-load-balancer, kong-ingress

I have created an Openshift cluster where my pods and services are running. Before creating an ingress, i deployed a Kong ingress controller that auto provisioned a Azure load balancer.

[image]

From my understanding, Kong uses Nginx that can be configured to be used as a load balancer itself. Why does it need a Load balancer to be provisioned by Cloud infrastructure on which kubernetes cluster is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have deployed the Kong Ingress controller with the service `type : LoadBalancer`

**LoadBalancer** service type is mainly use to expose the `Kubernetes` service using LB of **Cloud** provider.

ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

You can change the Kong service type to **ClusterIP** and it will as expected it will forward the request.

Comment: I deployed Kong ingress controller via helm chart. So I believe that the service type load balancer is a default for Kong ingress controller. ... My question was that why was there a need of cloud infrastructure load balancer when nginx used behind Kong is itself a load balancer

Comment: Loadbalancer is required to exposing the kong or nginx service to internet how can you expose the nginx or kong gateway to internet ? if you want to access it from internet as it's running inside the k8s service you need LB to expose the service to internet else it will be internal only.